# Getting error Uninitialized string offset: 0 in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$imageTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png","image/jpg");
$uploadData = array_shift($check);

print_r($uploadData)

    Array
    (
        [name] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpAADE.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 879394
    )



if(!in_array($uploadData['type'],$imageTypes)){
return false;
}
```

But i m getting error Uninitialized string offset: 0 in this below line

```
if(!in_array($uploadData['type'],$imageTypes)){
```

Comment: var_dump($uploadData) ??

Comment: Where is $check variable?

Comment: @vikamtyagi `$check` is already undefined on line 3.

Comment: i want to compare $uploadData['type'] value with in that array $imageTypes

Comment: @vikamtyagi and you do it perfectly with `in_array($uploadData['type'], $imageTypes)` so read the comments / answer

Comment: instead of print_r() could u try var_dump() since may be some length issue ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i have checked there is no length issue you can se also - array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "Chrysanthemum.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24)

Comment: @ChoiZ but i m getting output from that variable $check then compare it

Comment: should it not be `if(!in_array($uploadData[0]['type'],$imageTypes)){` ??

Comment: I haven't problem with this code http://pastebin.com/Eiimhd6n

Comment: This code works for me. The things I can see that can go wrong, given the amount of info that you have provided, is where `$check` is empty (or contains a non array value) - in the former case the line `array_shift($check);` will return `null` and `in_array()` will throw a `Undefined index: type` notice. An `array_shift` operation on a non-array will raise a `expects type array` warning. I suggest that your error is coming from somewhere else, possibly in code you have not provided. The error you get is strange - it's usually from dereferencing an empty string. Example: https://eval.in/134958

Comment: i dont know what was the issue, before start my code i add that code error_reporting(0);, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On your piece of code $check is undefined.

```
$imageTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png","image/jpg");

$uploadData = array_shift($check);

if(!in_array($uploadData['type'],$imageTypes)){
    return false;
}
```

Maybe you have to fix by:

```
$imageTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png","image/jpg");

$uploadData = array_shift($imageTypes);

if(!in_array($uploadData['type'],$imageTypes)){
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what might be happening here. The value you `array_shift()` from the `$check` array might be an empty string. Consider the following example:

```
$imageTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png","image/jpg");
$check = array(
    '' // empty string
);

$uploadData = array_shift($check);
var_dump(in_array($uploadData['type'], $imageTypes));
```

This raises the following warnings/notices:

> PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'type' in /Users/darragh/Sites/so.php on line 26
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /Users/darragh/Sites/so.php:0
>   PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /Users/darragh/Sites/so.php on line 26
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /Users/darragh/Sites/so.php:0
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in /Users/darragh/Sites/so.php on line 26
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0002     227040   1. {main}() /Users/darragh/Sites/so.php:0
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /Users/darragh/Sites/so.php on line 26
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0002     227040   1. {main}() /Users/darragh/Sites/so.php:0
>
> bool(false)

Example: https://eval.in/134971

Note that your notice `PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0` is in there, amongst other things.

Either way, you should make your code robust, perhaps raise an exception or deal with the error in your preferred manner. Something like:

```
$uploadData = array_shift($check);

// die if the data is not an array or if it does not have the expected key
if (!is_array($uploadData) || !array_key_exists('type', $uploadData)) {
    exit('$uploadData is not a valid array!');
}

// etc.
return !in_array($uploadData['type'], $imageTypes);
```

Example: https://eval.in/134972

Hope this helps.